# CGAffineTransformMakeScale cocoa?

Tags: cocoa, macos, transform

How can I use `CGAffineTransformMakeScale` in Cocoa?  On iPhone I do like this:

```
something.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2, 2);
```

But how can I do it on MAC?

Comment: You probably want: [something.layer setAffineTransform: CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2.0, 2.0)];

Answer (score 2):

`CGAffineTransform`, including all the related helper functions, works the same on Mac OS X as on iOS.

You do need to be linking against the Core Graphics or Application Services framework, and importing the header for whichever one you link against.

An NSView doesn't have a `transform` property like a UIView has, so if `something` was a UIView in your example, you will have to send your NSView a `scaleUnitSquareToSize:` message instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is unclear. The `CGAffineTransformMakeScale` function is available on the Mac and it works in exactly the same way as on iOS. It is part of the Application Services framework, so you will need to add that framework to your project and import it with:

```
#import <ApplicationServices/ApplicationServices.h>
```

If on the other hand you're referring to view transforms, then on the Mac, `NSView` objects are not layer-backed by default and do not have a `transform` property.

If you make the view layer-backed then you can access the view's `CALayer` object via the`layer` property of the view, and you can then apply a transform to that:

```
aView.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(2.0, 2.0, 0.0);
```

Note that both iOS and Mac OS X use `CATransform3D` structures for their layer transform property. If you want to set the layer transform to a `CGAffineTransform` then you need to use the `‑setAffineTransform:` method of `CALayer`.